# Can I subclass an Enum in which I have defined a __new__ method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

I want to create a pseudo-abstract (without going through the trouble of using ABC) Enum class, and to subclass it in different classes. All my subclasses would use the same `__new__` method, so I would like to define it in the superclass. Doing so, I encountered an `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_value_'` when I defined the subclass.

My attempt:

```
from enum import Enum
class BasePattern(Enum):
    def __new__(cls, pattern, groups):
        obj = object.__new__(cls)
        obj._value_ = pattern
        obj.groups = groups
class ExamplePattern(BasePattern):
    example1 = (r"regex", ["group1"])
```

Is there a simple way to get this to work, or would it be best to define the common `__new__` in each subclass? Should that be of concern, I use Python3.7.7.

Comment: May I ask what problem you are trying to solve? This feels like an XY problem,  and seems to create more problems instead of solving the original one

Comment: `__new__()` has to return something, which will become the value of the instance.  You're creating `None`s, here.

Comment: @jasonharper: that was my problem, it was so obvious that I missed it... If you want to turn your comment in an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @DeepSpace I am refactoring some code used to parse different types of legal texts. The final goal is to extend it (add new types of texts to its scope). Each type of text is currently handled by a specific enum, and they all look-alike. That is why I'm trying to use a superclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you use `__new__` you must return an object -- otherwise `None` is returned (which is the default for any function/method in Python).

As far as subclassing your own `Enum` base class -- as long as you don't have any members in that base class you will be fine -- put as much default behavior as you need.

*Side note*: In your `ExamplePattern` class, you don't need the outer set of parentheses; parentheses are a grouping operator, only needed to create tuples when there is ambiguity -- the comma, `,`, is what makes a tuple:

```
>>> a = 1, 2
>>> type(a)
<class 'tuple'>

>>> b = (5 )  # no comma
>>> type(b)
<class 'int'>
```